Logic Apps - Remove Diacritics in a String
Is there a built-in action in Azure Logic Apps that removes diacritics in a string and changes it to a standard letter? For example, if you have the string áóç, it becomes aoc.
After looking for other articles about it, it seems that the only option is to either use a paid connector or create an Azure Function which will remove the diacritics for me.

One approach to handle this is by utilizing the inline JavaScript action to clean the strings. The following code achieves the desired outcome:
const incomingTest = "This is my text with diacritics (áóç)" // Replace with your dynamic input
return incomingTest.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');

Good luck!

Use below powershell script, Which be copied from here
$src = @("áóç")
$normalized = $src.Normalize( [Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD )


$sb = new-object Text.StringBuilder

 $normalized.ToCharArray() | % { 
    if( [Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark) {
      [void]$sb.Append($_)
    }
  }
  
  
$sb.ToString()

and you need to introduce the azure automation account runbook in azure logic app to run this powershell script
